# How to change default location of xcode provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild

As we know xcode expects the provisioning profile in below directory

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
```

I'm trying to build the source code using xcodebuild commandline tool, i want to keep the profile as part of source code or any other location in machine. Now how to configure the xcode to use the profile from this new location.?